# How to restrict the user to not enter more than 8 numbers?

Tags: javascript

here is my implementation

```
    //I restrict the user to enter number only
    if (isNaN(e.target.value)) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1)
      e.target.type = 'number'
    }
    // here I forced the user to enter only 8 numbers
    if (e.target.value?.length > 8) {
       e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, 8)
    }
```

The above code works sometime sometime not. I need an alternative. is there any alternative that would be great. Thanks

Comment: please share your html too

Comment: Always try and include a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question. In this case it will be the Html along with the triggered javascript function. rather than just a small snippet

Comment: I see a strange place because there is no complete code, but I infer that it may be a spelling problem, it should be e.target.value.length instead of e.target.value?.length

Comment: @Ian that is [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), nothing wrong about it

Comment: @Reyno get new knowledge, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use String's [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)  method, to extract only 1st 8 characters, if length of input is greater than 8.

You also need to  set `max="99999999"` on input so that input doesn't go beyond `99999999` upon clicking `<input>`'s arrows.

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".num");

input.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  if(input.value.length > 8){
    input.value = input.value.substr(0,8);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" max="99999999" class="num">
```

Comment: "<input type="number" max="99999999">" Would be enough to resolve the "restrict the user to not enter more than 8 numbers"

Comment: @GilevichPetr I don't think so. I disabled the eventListener, and I was able to type more than 8 chars. I think `max` defines the limit of input's arrows. Also, I am using FF.

Answer (score 0):

**Why dont you make it simpler**

```html
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==8) return false;" max="99999999"/>
```

**type ="number"** are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries.
learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)